# tcl exec with cvs upd: why it exits?

Tags: exec, tcl, cvs

My question is very simple. Take into consideration the code snippets below:

```
set cvsPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/cvsnt/cvs.exe"
puts [exec $::cvsPath log filename]
puts "------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------"
```

This one prints the log and then "------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------".

```
set cvsPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/cvsnt/cvs.exe"
puts [exec $::cvsPath -n upd]
puts "------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------"
```

This one prints the update messages and exits. Why? How to prevent exiting?

P.S. The reason of exiting is `exec` with `cvs -n upd` input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're making csv.exe throw an error. Try catching it,

```
set cvsPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/cvsnt/cvs.exe"
if {[catch {puts [exec $::cvsPath -n upd]} result]} {puts $result}
puts "------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------"
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It worked, but `puts $result` printed nothing. Instead in the end it printed `------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------`. What is this???

Comment: Try looking at the documentation for cvs.exe. Whatever "-n" by itself is apparently makes it crash or throw an error.

Comment: The easiest way to find out is of course to try running `cvs -n upd` on the command line and see what it says is wrong

Comment: Of course it does not say something wrong because this the way how you tell cvs to imitate update process.

Comment: Thanks guys you helped me out to fins the answer! BTW @slebetman seams `cvs -n upd` throws an error, though it works without error message. It, maybe, prints the message through the stderr channel.

Answer (score 0):

`cvs -qn upd` instead of `cvs -n upd` works!

And the following works too:

```
if {[catch {exec $::cvsPath -n upd} result]} {puts $result}
puts "------------- END OF SCRIPT ---------------------"
```

I should mention that $result contains the update message, which simply means that `cvs -n upd` throws an error. Where as `cvs -qn upd` does not throw.

Comment: In that case, it would be `cvs` printing something to its stderr. (Well, probably.) Tcl's `exec` produces an error if *either* a message is written to stderr (without suitable redirections/flags) *or* if a non-zero exit code is returned by the subprocess.